# JVM running Glassfish crashes in Garbage-Collection, leaving only hs_err_-File

Tags: java, crash, garbage-collection, glassfish, jvm-crash

one of our new servers is crashing every 2 days or so, the JVM disappears and is leaving a hs_err_pidXYZ.log file.

The server is running glassfish v2 on jdk 1.6.0_26.
It has 32GB Memory and an i7-2600.
Memory consumption in jvisualvm looks healthy.

Have I found the correct Problem in the hs_err-File? (see below)
I have resized PermGen to 1g, it seams to helps a little.
Where to go from here?
What are best practices?

I isolted this in in the hs_err_files:

```
> Stack: [0x00007fd38d559000,0x00007fd38d65a000], 
> sp=0x00007fd38d658550,  free space=1021k Native frames: (J=compiled
> Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) V 
> [libjvm.so+0x69c334]  MarkSweep::follow_stack()+0x74 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x755e14]  PSMarkSweep::mark_sweep_phase1(bool)+0xe4 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x754cc1]  PSMarkSweep::invoke_no_policy(bool)+0x481 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x754803]  PSMarkSweep::invoke(bool)+0x83 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x8608f7]  VM_ParallelGCSystemGC::doit()+0xf7 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x86d7fa]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0x4a V 
> [libjvm.so+0x86cde2]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0x82
> V  [libjvm.so+0x86d053]  VMThread::loop()+0x193 V 
> [libjvm.so+0x86cb5e]  VMThread::run()+0x6e V  [libjvm.so+0x710adf] 
> java_start(Thread*)+0x13f
```

The full file is here:
http://pastebin.com/idW9RBNQ

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Do you use JNI in your application anywhere? If so, that is probably where the problem is.